# Dispatcher has no subscribers error on logging channel adapter

Tags: log4j, spring-integration

I am trying to log the inbound message using logging-channel-adapter.I have following spring integration configuration

```
<int:gateway service-interface="com.kipstor.events.EventGateway" default-request-channel="loggerChannel" />
<int:channel id="loggerChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" logger-name="kipstorLog" level="INFO" log-full-message="true" />
```

My log4j file configurations are follows

```
log4j.appender.kipstorLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kipstorLog.File=${catalina.home}/logs/kipstor.log
log4j.appender.kipstorLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.kipstorLog.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.kipstorLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.kipstorLog.layout=com.kipstor.kpp.util.CustomLogLayout
log4j.appender.kipstorLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %C{1}:%L - %m%n
```

However when service interface invoked following exception occurs

```
2018-02-23 11:17:17 ERROR SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler:37 - Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void com.kipstor.events.EventService.setEvent(java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])'.
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/KipstorRestApi.loggerChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:135)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:364)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:425)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:382)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:373)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.kipstor.events.EventService.setEvent(EventService.java:33)
at com.kipstor.events.EventService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6aec3e8b.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler$DelegatingErrorHandlingCallable.call(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:386)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:153)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
... 28 more
```

Any idea what has gone wrong?

Comment: The wiretap intercepts the message channel and logs the message but flow is still expecting to continue on to a subscriber of the channel.  What is the next step in the flow?

Comment: Thanks Joe. I just want to log this message. Once log this message, it will no longer require. Can you please let me know how to to pass this message to 'junk' channgel?

Comment: Remove the interceptor portion of your channel definition.

Comment: Thanks Joe . it worked ! . Now I have another problem. Since I am using custom layout as "log4j.appender.kipstorLog.layout=com.kipstor.kpp.util.CustomLogLayout" nothing logs into file. But as soon as I change this to "log4j.appender.kipstorLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout" logs genating in the file. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

> Once log this message, it will no longer require

So, you don't need the `<wire-tap>` at all.

There is just enough to have this:

```
<int:gateway service-interface="com.kipstor.events.EventGateway" default-request-channel="logger" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" logger-name="kipstorLog" level="INFO" log-full-message="true" />
```

I mean your gateway should just send messages to the `logger` channel.

Another your problem deserves a separate SO question. It's not related to the subject of this one.